# How can I serialize a tuple containing a basic type and an array of a basic type?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, serialization, tuples, datacontractserializer

In C# 4.0, I'm trying to serialize and deserialize a `Tuple<Guid, int[]>` using DataContractSerializer.  I've successfully serialized and deserialized type `Guid`, type `int[]` and type `Tuple<Guid, int>`.  If I try to serialize type `Tuple<Guid, int[]>`, everything compiles, but I get the following runtime exception:

```
Type 'System.Int32[]' with data contract name 
'ArrayOfint:http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays'
is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types
not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using
the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known 
types passed to DataContractSerializer.
```

My serialization and deserialization routines are simple:

```
public static string Serialize<T>(this T obj)
{
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType());
    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    using (var stm = new XmlTextWriter(writer))
    {
        serializer.WriteObject(stm, obj);
        return writer.ToString();
    }
}

public static T Deserialize<T>(this string serialized)
{
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (var reader = new StringReader(serialized))
    using (var stm = new XmlTextReader(reader))
    {
        return (T)serializer.ReadObject(stm);
    }
}
```

Why am I getting this exception, and what can I do to resolve this or get around it?  It would seem to me that a `Tuple` containing types that can be serialized should have no trouble being serialized.

Comment: Did you try any of the things that the error message suggests?

Comment: I've looked at DataContractResolver, but I'm uncertain how to use it in a way that will generically work for arbitrary combinations of basic or collection types inside Tuples.  All the examples I've found so far just use a known pre-existing class.  I need this to work for `Tuple<Guid, int[]>`, `Tuple<int[], int[]>`, `Tuple<int[], int>`, etc., and Tuples with 2 or 3 items/collections, preferably without a bunch of cases to test for each combination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
class Program
{
    public static class DataContractSerializerFactory<T>
    {
        private static IEnumerable<Type> GetTypeArguments(Type t, IEnumerable<Type> values)
        {
            if (t.IsGenericType)
                foreach (var arg in t.GetGenericArguments())
                    values = values.Union(GetTypeArguments(arg, values));
            else
                values = values.Union(new[] { t });
            return values;
        }

        public static DataContractSerializer Create()
        {
            return new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T), GetTypeArguments(typeof(T), new[] { typeof(T) }));
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = Tuple.Create(Guid.NewGuid(), new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 });

        var serializer = DataContractSerializerFactory<Tuple<Guid, int[]>>.Create();

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb))
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(writer, x);
            writer.Flush();
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Ought to work for any nested generic. Only the base type and leaf type arguments are considered. Should be easy if you want the in-between containers to be part of KnownTypes too.

Comment: Well, first I got an exception that only Generic types are supported for `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` when another part of my code called my serialize method modified to create a serializer with a factory as above with a non-generic type, but after adding a check for `typeof(T).IsGenericType` to fix that, I'm still getting the same error as in the OP.

Comment: With this code? I seem to get no errors for the example listed. GetGenericTypeDefinition should be called only if t.IsGenericType is true. Also try the code from the new edit. I would appreciate seeing a sample that bombs so I can fix it.

Comment: I was referring to your previous code, as I hadn't seen your update yet.  I'm testing this version now.

Comment: Still seeing the same exception.  I'll update the OP with the calling code as well as the updated serialization code.

Comment: I copied your code over - no exceptions running under VS 2012 (and targeting .NET 4.5) see pastebin here (http://pastebin.com/5Mp3FZf9)

Comment: My bad. We had some legacy code that was converting Tuples to object arrays from back when we were still using XMLSerializer.  That meant that the serializer wan't seeing a generic type, bypassing all the nice code you've implemented on SO.

Answer (score 3):

The error message tells you what you need to do; the problem is that arrays that are themselves members of embedded inside serialized types are not immediately recognized by the serializer. You just need to give it the metadata it needs to serialize that particular type.

Normally you'd do this by tacking an attribute on to your `DataContact`, like so:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(int[]))]
```

But since you're serializing a `Tuple` and not a user-defined class, you instead need to pass it into [the constructor:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa344259.aspx)

```
var knownTypes = new List<Type> { typeof(int[]) };
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Tuple<Guid, int[]>), knownTypes);
```

Comment: This approach works, and it works good! Even with my custom type; I simply add typeof(mytype), typeof(mytype[]) to knownTypes.